# Inequality problem with factorials

Tags: inequality, contest-math, factorial

I am not sure if this kind of "question" is welcome on MSE. Here is an olympiad-like problem that I would like to share with you:

> Let $a,b,c$ be nonnegative integers. Prove that
>   $$
> \frac{(a+b)!^2}{(2a)!(2b)!} + \frac{(b+c)!^2}{(2b)!(2c)!} + \frac{(c+a)!^2}{(2c)!(2a)!} \leq 1 + 2\frac{(a+b)!(b+c)!(c+a)!}{(2a)!(2b)!(2c)!}
> $$
>   When does equality hold?

I can provide an answer later if anyone is interested.

**Edit.** I hoped there would be more interest in this. Do you prefer I give hints before the answer?

Comment: a=b=c? Most if not all "olympiad" type inequalities hold true for that case. I would assume this is some variation of AM-GM? (will look deeper later)

Comment: I would assume $a=b=c$ as trivial and $2b\geq a+c$ or $a+c\geq 2b$,though if it's correct I have no idea how to prove it :D

Comment: Any hints would be really helpful.

Comment: Although too advanced for my tastes, I can say (having done some Olympiad-style inequality problems before (I thoroughly enjoy and am interested in Olympiad-style maths questions!)), some basic facts about factorials, the AM-GM inequality and potentially the rearrangement inequality are needed to get far for this question. Hope this helps!